# Will Small Business Server 2008 Standard work well in a 5-10 user environment?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-sbs

I'm helping a company put together a new office that will have 5-10 users.  They'll need a domain controller, a small file/print server, a VPN server, and a terminal server.  Exchange is being hosted off-site.

I'm use to working with 50 - 100 users and I usually go with Server 2008 Standard or Enterprise depending on the situation.  I've never done a SBS implementation before and am wondering what all it entails?

Will SBS 2008 Standard be able to be used as a domain controller on one piece of hardware (that is also DNS and DHCP), a file/print server on another hardware, a RRAS server on another, and a Terminal Server on another server?  (I'm thinking of trying to handle VPN on a firewall instead of a server).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep that'll work. Server 2008 R2 Foundation may be a better fit (depends on how your setting it up). I'd definitely virtualize everything and separate the various function as best you can.

Comment: So Foundation supports virtualization?  I know nothing of Foundation either :)  I like this idea.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you back up Active Directory properly, and frequently. Rebuilding a domain is not fun, even if it is for just 10 users.

Comment: Hyper-V Server is free and you can run just about any version of Windows on it; Foundation doesn't come with virtualization rights, Standard/Enterprise/DC do.

Comment: +1. I was going to mention Foundation edition until I read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot have more than one SBS on a domain.

Plus, why use SBS if you don't need Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work just fine. I've used SBS 2003 in a 30 user environment with no problems.